# Output of Python script not shown in Eclipse console

Tags: python, eclipse, console, output

Using Eclipse Juno under Windows I have configured an external tool that calls the `Python.exe` program, with a Python script file to run as argument (the latter in between double quotes, like `"C:\script.py"`).

I have also double checked that in the external tools configuration window, in the "Common" tab the option "Allocate console" is set.

However, when I now run this external tool, no Python output at all is shown in the Eclipse console.

On the other hand, when I define another external tool, calling cmd.exe, then I can see all output from that shell in the Eclipse console fine.

Moreover, when I run `python.exe "C:\script.py"` directly from a Windows shell window, then I can also see all output comming from this Python script. Also when I run the Python script in Eclipse using PyDev directly (where I have developed the script), then again its output is shown nicely in the Eclipse/PyDev console.

So, the Eclipse console does theoretically work fine with external tools, and the called Python script does print output. But running the Python script as external tool does not show any output in the Eclipse console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a limitation of Windows that some output cannot be read other programs. I don't understand it myself yet, but it might be related to [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/13742).

Comment: Well, I switched to PyCharm and it works great, IMHO much better than Eclipse. At least in this case :)